# How in vuex get method to call action method?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

In @vue/cli 4.0.5 / vuex 3 app with data reading from Laravel Backend API
I keep some parameters in database settings table and I want to read them once
and to keep it in vuex storage.
I check if site_name value is empty I
call retrieveSiteName action and got error :

```
 Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined"
```

In my src/store/index.js :

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {// store data
        status: '',
        token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
        user: null,
        site_name: '', // I need to read this value once
        ...
    }, // state: { // store data

    getters: {
        ...


        site_name(state) {
            if (state.site_name.length > 0) {
                return state.site_name
            }
            let site_name = localStorage.getItem('site_name')
            if (site_name != null ) {
                return site_name
            }
            // this.actions.retrieveSiteName(state)

            // state.this.dispatch('retrieveSiteName')
            this.dispatch('retrieveSiteName') // Error Here!

            return ''
        }, // site_name(state) {
        ...

    actions: { // async methods
        retrieveSiteName(context) {
            console.log('retrieveSiteName::')
            let apiUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL
            axios.post(apiUrl + '/app_settings', 'site_name')
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log('retrieveSiteName response::')
                    console.log(response)

                    context.commit('refreshSiteName', response.data.site_name)

                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error)
                })
        }, // retrieveSiteName(context) {
```

Which is valid way of calling retrieveSiteName from get name method ?

Thanks!

Comment: _"Which is valid way of calling retrieveSiteName from get name method"_  You don't.

Comment: Vuex getters **must** be pure functions - you can reference other functions (imported from other ES6 modules) but you can not call a Vuex method from another Vuex method or getter and you can not call a Vuex action from a Vuex method or getter. Vuex action can dispatch other actions or commit mutations - but not the opposite.

Comment: Can you advice some practical decision here?
I described my situation : I do not like to read the same data from db(As I do now) any time when 
I move to other page.
That is different case when user is logged and all his personal info is read from db 
and stored in vuex store. User can open any pages of site frontend(say from bookmark)
and I need once is to read data from db and stored in vuex store...